# JQuery - удалить стиль, добавленный с помощью функции .css()

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как сделать что бы при клики на кнопку, применялись стили функции .css() и показывалось меню, а потом при втором клике стили этой кнопки обнулялись?

```
[Codepen]https://codepen.io/nord18/pen/aQJvYQ
```

Comment: Никак. Использовать функцию `addClass` вместо функции `css`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
  $(".add").click(function(){
    $("a").css({"color":"red","font-size":"24px"});
  });
  $(".remove").click(function(){
   $("a").css("color","");
  });
});
```

```css
a{color:green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">Тест</a>
<button class="add">Добавить стиль</button>
<button class="remove">Удалить стиль</button>
```

Можно просто задавать пустые значения, тогда стиль пропадет. В примере добавляю размер шрифта и цвет, удаляю только цвет.

Answer (score 0):

Решил вот так:

```
$(".page__btn-select").click(function() {
   $(this).toggleClass("btn-select");
   $("ul").toggle();
});
```